# Get a TextView in an AsyncTask - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to publish the result of my AsyncTask (a string) in a textView.

Here is my Main:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(this);
    readRss.execute();
    ......
}
```

Here is my AsyncTask:

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

public ReadRss(Context context){
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ProcessXml();
    return null;
}

private void ProcessXml() {
    //HERE CREATE MY STRING
    String myresult="example";

    TextView txt_ris = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_ris);  <---HOW CAN I DO THIS?
    txt_ris.setText(myresult);   

            }

        }
    }
}
```

FindViewById don't work in the AsyncTask so how can i get the TextView in here?
Maybe i can pass it as a paramiter in the AsyncTask, What is the syntax?

Comment: Move the code to edit the text view inside the postExecute

Comment: You cannot change the UI from a background thread anyway, even if you do pass the TextView as a parameter. What you can do is use the [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post the event when the data is fetched, listen for that event in your activity, and change the text upon that event.

Comment: I can't return the string back to the main? Can u do a example of EventBus?

Comment: onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() are called on main thread. So you could set the text in onPostExecute() which is called after doInBackground() has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place UI work in `onPostExecute` method, since doInBackground executes in not UI thread

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    public ReadRss(Context context){
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        TextView txt_ris = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_ris);
        txt_ris.setText(myresult); 
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return ProcessXml();
    }

    private String ProcessXml() {
        //HERE CREATE MY STRING
        return "example";
    }
}
```

Comment: protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return ProcessXml();
    }   Here i get an error: doInBackground(Void...)clashes with doInBackground(Params) ... attempting to use incompatible type.

Comment: Don't work becouse getting error when i pass the string from ProcessXml() to onPostExecute. I'm getting error using return and trying to modify void methods

Comment: Provide full code of `processXml()` and full stacktrace, please

Comment: Also I've added my answer. It was my misspelling. Now I wrote `private String ProcessXml()` instead of `private void ProcessXml()`

Comment: I just define my String on the top of AsyncTask and set the value of the TextView in the inPostExecute(); and then implementing the Chisko answer too. With this 3 modify work fine. Thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

For your TextView to be correctly referenced you need a context and you already have a reference to your starting Activity in your AsyncTask constructor, so you can do something like:

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

     private TextView tv;
     private YourStartingActivity activity;

     public ReadRss(Context context){
         activity = (YourStartingActivity)context;
         tv = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.txt_ris)
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         ...
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
         (follow Michael Spitsin instructions here)
     }

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Your answer seem right, but i don't know now how to pass the string from ProcessXml() to onPostExecute. I'm getting error using return in some methods (Michael Spitsin solution), can you please correct the return and void method for do this?

Comment: I just define my String on the top of AsyncTask and set the value of the TextView in the inPostExecute(); and then implementing your answer too. With this 3 modify work fine. Thank a lot

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer :) sorry for not replying before, I was busy.

Comment: Sure man, I just need some more points for the upvote, now I can't cuz is a new profile.